How to set User-Managed secret when using firebase cli for app hosting secret creation
When I was using the firebase app hosting with next.js project. I have noticed the secret manager cost a lot.
Within further research, I found the cost is mainly concentrated on the replica storage. The default secret location will be set to "Automatically replicated" to many locations, which cost me A LOT.
Is there any ways to set the secret location the user-managed? Or the cheaper way to manage the secret for app hosting.

I encountered the same problem, but I think the only way to do these is just manually create the secret by using GCP UI or gcloud cli.
In the Secret Manager UI, when creating the screct it will ask whether the secret should auto replicated or manually set locations.
